# Calculate ratios of a group and a subgroup in a dataframe with many separate groups

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way (without using loops) to calculate ratios of a group(material number)and then subgroup(date). For example, I have:

```
Mat#    Date     Value    
A    1/1/2010    2
B    1/1/2010    6
A    1/1/2008    4
C    1/1/2010    6
A    1/1/2020    2
B    1/1/2020    6
A    1/1/2021    4
C    1/1/2020    6
```

I want:

```
 Mat#    Date     Value    Ratio
A    1/1/2010    2          N/a
A    1/1/2008    4          2
A    1/1/2020    2          0.5  
A    1/1/2021    4          2  
B    1/1/2010    6          N/A  
B    1/1/2020    6           1
C    1/1/2010    6          N/A 
C    1/1/2020    6          1
```

The code I am currently using is:

```
lol = df%>%
     arrange(df$materialNumber,df$EKPO_Price_Date) %>%
     mutate(log10ratio = abs(log10(as.numeric(df$netPriceinPD) / lag(as.numeric(df$netPriceinPD)))))
```

Ignore the log10, same theory applies

But currently with this code, it is sorting the data properply, however, calculating the ratio for each once and ignorning the subgroups.

I  want to determine the ratio of value in the df (arranged by material number and then date) for the value of the current row of that material number/ previous value of the current row of that material number

Comment: I don't understand how you are calculating your ratio

Comment: ps: when you use `dplyr` sintax you don't need to write `df$`. Delete it in every line.

Comment: @Edo, i wouldnt worry too much about the syntax of how i wrote the code to calculate the ratio, had to do some basical manuplaition to get it to work ( can obviously be cleaned up), but thanks for the tip, went ahead and removed from my code.

Comment: can you explain how you want the ratio to be calculated? I can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @Edo, I just want to determine the ratio of value in the df (arranged by material number and then date) for the value of the current row of that material number/ previous value of the current row of that material number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way. You need to use the `dplyr` verb `group_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  
  # covert to date
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%

  arrange(Mat, Date) %>% 
  group_by(Mat) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = Value / lag(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   Mat   Date       Value Ratio
#>   <chr> <date>     <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A     2008-01-01     4  NA  
#> 2 A     2010-01-01     2   0.5
#> 3 A     2020-01-01     2   1  
#> 4 A     2021-01-01     4   2  
#> 5 B     2010-01-01     6  NA  
#> 6 B     2020-01-01     6   1  
#> 7 C     2010-01-01     6  NA  
#> 8 C     2020-01-01     6   1
```

In this case you need to use `ungroup` to remove the logical groups you created with `group_by`. If you don't write it, you may have troubles in your analysis in future steps.

Comment: actually hmm, it doesnt seem to be sorting by date. groups by material number, but the dates are not sorted properly, therefore the ratios being calculated are not correct.

Comment: You should provide an example. But first: check out str(df). Probably the variable Date is a character instead of a date. Try to force it to date format. Then it  should work.

Comment: I've update it my answer to add the transformation to Date